# Css script for dropdown looks as a button

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I need a css class for dropdown to look it as a button as gmail dropdown actions. (drop down "More")

Comment: Just copy their css if it has to look exactly like that...

Comment: But they are not using html select for their drop down. So the arrow cannot be changed using css

Comment: you said dropdown - not `<select>` - be more specific in questions.

Answer (score 1):

Google is not using select for their dropdowns. It's divs with some javascript
You can either style your select with javascript (you can choose from [these js libraries](http://www.noupe.com/php/beautiful-forms.html), or google for "beautiful forms with javascript") or use the same code that Google uses (divs, spans, unordered lists).

Answer (score 0):

[CSS Menu Maker](http://cssmenumaker.com/drop_down_css_menu.php)

If none of these fit what you are looking for, pull the css code out of the page source and edit it to your liking. This can be done with all CSS and no javascript if that's what you are looking for, also make sure you have an understanding of styling lists in CSS. [CSS list styling](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp)